# TFS build cannot publish test results if TFS server is in domain different from drop location

Tags: mstest, tfsbuild

I have the problem with failing TFS build if my drop location is in domain different from TFS server. The error I get is

```
     Results file: C:\TestResults\CPU_Release.trx
     Test Settings: Default Test Settings
     Waiting to publish...
     Publishing results of test run buildAgent@computername 2011-01-03 15:31:38_Any CPU_Release to http://tfsserver:8080/...
     .....................The drop share directory "\\computername\Builds\projectName\CI_1.0.193.0" could not be accessed.
     The drop share directory "\\computername\Builds\projectName\CI_1.0.193.0" could not be accessed.
     1:6>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(1403,5): error MSB6006: "MSTest.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\Users\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
```

How can at least I skip publishing test results? I tried to set up property

```
<PublishTestResults>false</PublishTestResults>
```

but it does not help. I use TFS server 2008.

Comment: TFS is pretty crap if accessing via different domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [workaround](http://www.donovanbrown.org/post/How-to-prevent-publishing-test-results-with-team-build.aspx) finally helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Wish I could speak to the **PublishTestResults** setting, but what appears to be happening is the tool is trying to authenticate across domains or doesn't have the appropriate permissions on the network drop location.

Two things you can do:

1. Add the username and password needed to access the droplocation to the [Credential Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Store-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials-for-automatic-logon) of the build agent machine.
2. Verify that this credential has the correct permissions to this network resource.

The Credential Manager was introduced in XP and beyond.